# Determining if a facebook application has been bookmarked from the Facebook REST API

Tags: facebook

I'm running a Facebook App as an iframe and need to discover if it's already been bookmarked. I know it's trivial to tell if a user of your facebook app has already installed it, but how do I go about determining if they've already bookmarked it?

To be clear, I'm not referring to a browser bookmark, I'm talking about the bookmarks bar within Facebook.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  The justification I have seen for it in the forums is to prevent applications from rewarding users who have bookmarked the app, or nagging users who haven't.

The closest you can get is to go to the settings of your application in the Developer app, and there is an option under Canvas -> Bookmark URL where you can specify the entry point of your app when a user clicks the bookmark.  The URL defaults to your Canvas URL if it's not filled in.

You could theoretically add a parameter or change the location of the Bookmark URL in order to identify a user that clicked a bookmark.  Obviously this isn't ideal, as you can't tell when a user removes a bookmark, and a user can still get into the app without clicking the bookmark.

Comment: I guess I'm not following, because you gave me exactly what I want.  A way of determining if the user has accessed the app through the bookmarks bar.  This is ideal :)

Comment: Ah, glad I could help.  I thought you were asking if it was possible to query Facebook and ask "Has this user bookmarked my app?".  There isn't a way to do that with FQL or the API, but you can indeed create a "bookmark entry point".  Good luck with it!

Answer (score 2):

FQL:

select bookmarked from permissions where uid = *facebook_id*